# No visible indicator of where to drag/move an Outlook window

Tags: windows-7, email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013, title-bar

The new version of Outlook I am using (365) doesn't provide any visible contrast between the title bar and ribbon bar in windows it displays. You also can only drag (move) the window if you grab it by the title bar (i.e. grabbing  the any other location doesn't allow moving the window).

Take a look at part of the main Outlook window, below:

[image: Main Outlook mail window]

Email windows are even worse; the window whitespace extends to the bottom of the window:

[image: Outlook email example]

When I change the Outlook theme to dark grey and the background to calligraphy it looks like this:

[image: Outlook with dark gray and calligraphy]

Note that I still can't see the dividing line between the 'title bar' (where I can drag) and the menu bar (where dragging doesn't work). In addition, Calligraphy hides the close/window/minimize icons for the window.

My question: Is it possible to change the appearance of Outlook so that the title bar is distinguishable from the rest of the window?

About my system: I am running MS Outlook 2013 (part of Office 365 ProPlus) running on top of Windows 7 64 bit (Enterprise version). Windows is personalized to use an Aero theme. I prefer to run Areo because it allows me a preview view of any minimized windows; I run about 30 windows at a time and this makes it easier to find the particular window I need.

Comment: @Sun: added a section to question showing that changing Outlook theme doesn't help as a solution for my drag and drop question.

Comment: The themes Areo, Windows 7 basic, and Windows Classic don't show a separate title bar. All of the 'high contrast' schemes do show a seperate title bar (at the cost of making my eyes bleed from the color schemes). As I mentioned in my question, I was hoping for an Aero solution because navigating two dozen windows without Areo is very painful. Where I work that many programs are required, and I prefer not to have Outlook dictate the look of my desktop. I would have thought Microsoft would have checked to see what problems a new Outlook user interface might cause in common Windows schemes.

Comment: I was able to get a contrasted title bar versus ribbon when I used high contrast themes. Ugly but you can have a visual separation if you care enough to endure "ugly" color combinations.

Answer (score 1):

Not for Outlook 2013. You can only have it in Outlook 2016 (Colorful theme).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/633057)

Comment: @TobySpeight You can't do it is a perfectly valid answer. It would be better backed up by some references - but it is still a valid answer.